# How to extend std library containers to get notified when individual elements are changed

Tags: c++, c++11, std

I would like to extend std library containers so that the application is notified when ever state of the container gets changed. For example, when a new item is added to a list, I want the container to call a method in application with certain information. My requirement is to track which memory addresses get changed as a result of a given operation. For example, if insertion of a new element results in a modification of some object internal to the list, I would like to know the start address of that object as well as the size of the object, so that I know roughly which area of the memory got changed.

UPDATE:
Looks like my question is not that clear. I don't want to intercept calls to grab values. Rather, what I want is to track how memory is changed as a result of an operation. For example when a new element is added to a binary tree, a pointer in some node in the tree gets updated to point to the newly added node. When this happens, I want to get notified with the address of this node as well as the size of the Node's class, so I can safely say that a memory addess in range start_address to start_address + sizeof(NodeType) got changed. With some help from a custom memory pool + custom allocator, I can use this information to do a incremental state dump.

Comment: Have you tried something? You could provide your own implementation of a container.

Comment: This seems very open-ended (an interesting idea): do you want to worry about threads?  In that case, you'd have to have some notion of thread-safety, either in the container or the callback?  One thought to get inside the container is to allow a "protected" (in the C++ public/protected/private sense) interface that can have people who inherit access to certain methods.

Comment: Is this an XY-problem regarding debugging?

Comment: @rts1 for the moment I am not concerned about threading at all.

Comment: @Ceros Of course one way would be to write the containers from scratch, but that option is kept as the last resort :)

Comment: @DieterLücking Not sure what an XY-problem is. But no, this is not for debugging. This is to design something that can dump state incrementally with very low overhead.

Comment: I more and more like the idea of the standard providing certain parts of the interface that are protected: then a user could extend/get information without having to necessarily rewrite the standard class.  So, vector might always have a virtual? method called extend () that has an empty implementation, and an extending class could be "notified" when that happens.  Of course, that puts virtual methods in concrete classes, which is probably not a good idea ... so you might be able to do it with templates and provide a "well-named" function that gets seen when you want to intercept, else empty.

Comment: size of object cannot be changed at runtime you seem not to understand problem properly

Comment: (I feel like I am whiteboarding .. ;)  To expand on the idea above, have a generic function named "expand" that gets called when the (say vector) expands.  If you provide a particular specialization (either by inheriting or making a function with a specfic type), that function will get called for you when the vector expands.  That way you could preserve the run-time performance (an empty "do nothing" function would get optimized away), but still allow the notion of a callback with your specialization of a generic function/class.  Thoughts?

Comment: @rts I bet we XY-problem here and nobody really needs it. For example it is easier to make a thin wrapper and store it instead of actual type and intercept move ctor.

Comment: @Slava I don't know what an XY-problem is (we are saying one thing and meaning another?)  And yes, this may be of limited utility, but given how much we depend on standard containers, it might nice to have the standard allow this when we need it.  But your point is taken.

Comment: @rts1 read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: A thin wrapper might work: it depends on how much of the interface you need.   One reason to inherit is you want a LOT of interface re-used: a thin wrapper is a good idea when you just want some (and don't want to forwards tons and tons of interface).

Comment: @rts1 you can create compatible to `std::vector` interface and provide described functionality - replacement in code should be easy (if code written properly). I doubt anybody would bother to implement it.

Comment: I think the entire idea is basically a nonstarter: `std::string& ref = myVec[2]; ref[3] = '4';` There is literally no possible implementation of myVec that could to detect this change.

Comment: @MooingDuck I do not expect to handle this or anything of this sort. I can always restrict the usage to suit my need.

Answer (score 2):

Out the box, the standard containers don't offer notifications quite like those you describe.

As an example;

```
template<
    class T,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<T>
> class vector;
```

Containers have essentially two extension points - the type `T` and the allocator `Allocator`. The internals of the container, e.g. the nodes, internal pointers, counters etc. are not exposed for customisation.

To mimic the hooks you desire, you need to leverage these two extension points of the standard containers. If they prove insufficient, then you will need to build your own container.

Providing a custom allocator can assist in getting notified of object (for containers that use them, this includes internal node objects) construction, destruction and allocations, deallocations etc. Given the example usage, a custom allocator could be all that is required; these actions typically correspond to container growth, object creation and destruction etc. Allocators provide (during allocation) and are provided (during construction and destruction), the addresses of the memory being altered.

You could also wrap the type being used in the container to notify you of changes to its state, but this could be overkill, and difficult to identify changes made by the container itself and those by clients of the container.

Further, you could wrap the containers to provide the hooks you need, and then stub the rest of the required functionality through to a private member (or base class) of the required container. You could even template this to support a number of container types.

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the example you gave of returning addresses to internal memory locations in a list.  If you have different threads working with iterators that could be invalidated, you lock the container until that task is finished.

The other example, notifying when a container allocates more storage, is okay. Here's a really simple example.  I only implemented push() which calls push_back on the underlying vector.  You can't even access the data you have already pushed, but that will be easy for you to add.

```
template <class T>
class notifyvector {
    std::vector<T> _vector;
    size_t _capacity;
    static const size_t initial_capacity = 20;

public:
    notifyvector() : _capacity(initial_capacity) {
        _vector.reserve(initial_capacity);
    }

    void push(T value){
        _vector.push_back(value);
        if (_capacity < _vector.capacity()){
            // the vector has grown
            _capacity = _vector.capacity();
            do_notify(_capacity);
        }
    }

    void do_notify(size_t newcap){
        // all you
        std::cout << "the vector has grown to " << newcap << std::endl;
    }
};
```

The point of the exercise is to demonstrate a wrapper that provides exactly the type of notification you want in a class that controls all input and output to the underlying container.  This allows it to detect events and send whatever notification you want.

You could probably allow access to a const reference of the underlying container (read only), and detect the events you want to notify in the write access, which must go through your container's functions.